# How to save export highchart image with out dialog box?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

By the following code i am able to download highchart image, I want to save  the image automatically in my disk with out prompting the dialog box. Is it possible ?

Code:

```
chart1.exportChart({ type: 'image/jpeg', filename: 'my-jpg' }, { subtitle: { text: ''} });
```

Comment: the prompt box asked by browser not highchart function

Comment: Thanks !. But i need skip that prompting and save the file. Is it possible ?

Comment: Depending on the browser you can configure it to automatically download files to a directory without prompting. As far as I know it is not programmable from within a webpage itself - for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It is a javaScript code running on the browser and it cannot access your disk because of security reasons.